# Counting words with particular order

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many possibilites are there to arrange the letters $ABCDEF$ with the condition that $B$ must never directly follow $A$, $C$ never $B$, $D$ never $C$, $E$ never $D$, $F$ never $E$.

I tried to use the inclusion-exclusion principle:

Let $S$ be the set of words consisting of $ABCDEF$ and $A_1$ the words where $B$ *does* directly follow $A$ and successively to $A_5$ the set of words where $F$ *does* directly follow $E$. We then have

$\bigl | S\setminus \bigl ( \bigcup_{j=1}^5 A_j\bigr ) \bigr | = |S| + \sum_{k=1}^5 (-1)^k\sum_{A\subset[5], |A|=k} \bigl | \bigcap_{i\in A}A_i\bigr |$

It is clear that $|S|=6!$.

Now for term $-\sum_{j=1}^5 |A_j|$ I computed $ - 5\cdot5!$, because for all words with e.g. $B$ following $A$ I can think of $AB$ as one fixed element in $ABCDEF$.

But I can't proceed from here, since my method does not work when I intersect the sets $A_j$.

EDIT: As  JMoravitz commented, it should work with this method. I would obtain:

$\bigl | S\setminus \bigl ( \bigcup_{j=1}^5 A_j\bigr ) \bigr | =6!-\binom{5}{1}5!+\binom{5}{2}4!-\binom{5}{3}3!+\binom{5}{4}2!-\binom{5}{5}1!$

Is this correct?

Comment: "*Since my method does not work when I intersect the sets $A_j$*"  What makes you say that?  Suppose that you are looking at $A_1$ and $A_4$ for instance, where $B$ follows $A$ and $E$ follows $D$.  So you are arranging the letters $(AB),C,(DE),F$.  Alternatively if you are intersecting $A_1$ and $A_2$, you have $B$ following $A$ and $C$ following $B$, so treat it instead as arranging the letters $(ABC),D,E,F$.  In either case, you are just arranging four elements.

Comment: You should be correct. I will make an update!